# Why is Export-PnPFlows Skipping Flows?

Tags: powershell, power-automate

This is my first post, so please pardon formatting errors!
I've been trying to export my tenant's Power Automate flows via Export-PnPFlow. I have a few hundred flows, so doing it by hand isn't really feasible.
The script works well enough for some flows, but is throwing an error for others, but I can't see why.
It does not seem to be caused by if it's enabled/disabled, owned by a certain user, in a certain environment, or in/out of a solution.
The ones that work, work perfectly; the others give the following error:

```
Export-PnPFlow : {"error":{"code":"ConnectionAuthorizationFailed","message":"The caller object id is '08#####-#####-####-###'. Connection '2#####-#####-####-####' to 'shared_logicflows' cannot be used to activate this flow, either because 
this is not a valid connection or because it is not a connection you have access permission for. Either replace the connection with a valid connection you can access or have the connection owner activate the flow, so the connection is shared with you in the context of 
this flow."}}
At C:\Users\jutrust\script.ps1:13 char:21
+ ...             Export-PnPFlow -Environment $environment -Identity $flow. ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Export-PnPFlow], HttpRequestException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.PowerPlatform.PowerAutomate.ExportFlow
```

My question is, is it possible that these flows are deleted and that's why I get this error? If so, how can I check?
Code below.

```
 Connect-PnPOnline -url https://########.sharepoint.com
 $environments = get-pnppowerplatformenvironment
 foreach($environment in $environments)
    {
        $flows = Get-PnPFlow -Environment $environment -AsAdmin 
        foreach ($flow in $flows) 
            {
                    $filename = $flow.Properties.DisplayName.Replace(" ", "")
                    $timestamp = Get-Date -Format "yyyymmddhhmmss"
                    $exportPath = "$($filename)_$($timestamp)"
                    $exportPath = $exportPath.Split([IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars()) -join '_'
          
                    Export-PnPFlow -Environment $environment -Identity $flow.Name | Out-File "C:\Users\jutrust\documents\$exportPath.json"
           }
     }
```

Help!
Edit: Updated error code

Comment: The code does not match the line the error message is talking about: `Export-PnPFlow -Environment $_.Properties.EnvironmentDeta`. In your code this is `Export-PnPFlow -Environment $environment`. You probably get the error because of the typo: `EnvironmentDeta` --> `EnvironmentData` or is that abbreviated from `EnvironmentDetails` perhaps?

Comment: Ah, I tried to do this with two different, but very similar scripts and pasted the error code of the wrong one. I've corrected it in the post, but the error reads almost exactly the same